# Regex: select each occurrence of a character up until another character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a couple of lines in a document which looks something like that:

```
foo-bar-foo[Foo - Bar]
```

I'd like to select every `-` character up until the first `[` bracket on every line. Thus the `-` in the square brackets shouldn't be selected.

How can I achieve that with a Regex?

I already have this regex `/.+?(?=\[)/g`, which selects every character until the first `[` but I only want the `-`.

Edit: I want to replace these selected characters with the `sed` command (GNU).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E ':a; s/^([^[-]+)-/\1/; ta'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/UG78Ew):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='foo-bar-foo[Foo - Bar]'
sed -E ':a; s/^([^[-]+)-/\1/; ta' <<< "$s"
# => foobarfoo[Foo - Bar]
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enabling POSIX ERE syntax (so that there is no need to escape capturing parentheses and the `+` quantifier)
- `:a` - an `a` label
- `s/^([^[-]+)-/\1/` - finds one or more chars other than `[` and `-` from the start of string capturing this substring into Group 1 (`\1`) and then matches a `-` char
- `ta` - jumps to `a` label upon a successful replacement